# $\forall a > 0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $x^2 > a$

Tags: solution-verification, real-numbers

I'm trying to prove:

> $\forall a > 0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $x^2 > a$.

Here is my attempt.

> Given $a > 0$, we have $a + 1 > 1$, meaning that $(a+1)^2 > a$, and $a + 1 > a$, so we have $(a+1)^2 > a + 1 > a$, so it suffices to take $x = a + 1$.

How is this?

Comment: perfect for me.

Comment: Your proof seems fine.

As an alternative, by contradiction, assume $\forall x\in \mathbb R$

$$x^2<a \iff -\sqrt a <x<\sqrt a$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is absolutely correct. But here's a more "mathematician's way" to reach the same conclusion-

By the Archimedean property, $\forall a\in \mathbb R$, $\exists n\in \mathbb N$ such that $n\cdot 1=n>a$. Also, because of the completeness of $\mathbb R$, $\forall y\in \mathbb R$, we have $\sqrt y\in \mathbb R$. So, $x=\sqrt n\in \mathbb R$. Finally,
$$x^2=\left(\sqrt n \right)^2=n>a$$

This completes the proof.